# join sed output

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm looking to somehow pass the output of the following command:

```
$ sed -n '5p' file-A
```

into

```
$ sed '5 c\
> "string extracted from previous sed command" file-B
```

So basically, I want to replace line x of a file A with line x of a file B. I'm open to any other better options.

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to go with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, with two file sample:

`file-A`:

```
abc
abc
abc
abc
line5-file-A
abc
```

And `file-B`:

```
def
def
def
def
line5-file-B
def
```

You can do like this:

```
% sed -e "5 c\\$(sed -n '5p' file-A)" file-B
def
def
def
def
line5-file-A
def
```

Then line 5 in `file-B` will be replaced by line 5 in `file-A`.

You should use `-i` to make the change inplace.

Another way is to use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(FNR==5){a=$0};next}{if(FNR==5){$0=a};print}' file-A file-B
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and great examples, you are the best! really saved my life :) thank you once again mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best way to go, but it works

```
$ sed "5s/^.*$/$(sed -n '5p' file-A)/" file-B
```